# Issues with stable coin code compiling

Tags: blockchain, stablecoins

Including all code here:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract stablecoin{
address ceo = ;
mapping(address => uint) tokens;
function approval(address _owner, address _approved,uint _tokenId){
    require(tokens[_owner]==_tokenId);
    tokens[_approved]=_tokenId;
}
function transfer(address _to, uint _amount) public payable{
    require(_amount <= tokens[msg.sender]);
    tokens[msg.sender]-=_amount;
    tokens[_to]+=_amount;
}
function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint){
    return tokens[_owner];
}
function ownerOf(uint _tokenId) public view returns(address){
    return tokens[_id].address;
}
function TransferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _tokenId) payable{
    require(tokens[_from]==_tokenId);
    tokens[_from]=0;
    tokens[_to]=_tokenId;
}
function approve(address _approved, uint _tokenId) payable{
    require(tokens[msg.sender]==_tokenId);
    tokens[_approved]=_tokenId;
}
function mint(address _to, uint _amount) payable{
    tokens[ceo]+=_amount;
    tokens[_to]+=_amount;

}
function burn(address _from,uint _amount) payable{
    tokens[ceo]-=_amount;
    tokens[_from]-=_amount;
}
}
```

Comment: Please include more code. How is `tokens` defined?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! here is the top half of the code:                           
        address ceo = ;
 mapping(address => uint) tokens;
 function approval(address _owner, address _approved,uint _tokenId){
  require(tokens[_owner]==_tokenId);
  tokens[_approved]=_tokenId;
 }
 function transfer(address _to, uint _amount) public payable{
  require(_amount <= tokens[msg.sender]);
  tokens[msg.sender]-=_amount;
  tokens[_to]+=_amount;
 }
 function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint){
  return tokens[_owner];  ------ let me know if this helps!

Comment: Please edit the question to add the code, in a comment it is unreadable. Please include a self contained contract that we can compile and test, or else we will be just guessing what's wrong.

Comment: understood, how can I add a self-contained contract to this comment? or do I have to make a new post altogether

Comment: You can edit your own question and add the code there.

Comment: Full code is included

Comment: Well, the problem is that you aren't tracking ownership. You'll need a mapping to track the tokenId to owner relationship. Something like `mapping(uint256 =>address) public owners`, also modify when the relationship changes to update the mapping. The contract seems mixing ERC20 and ERC721 concepts, I'd recommend to start with one of the concepts before merging both.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but if "tokens" is a mapping defined as

```
  mapping(uint=>address) tokens;
```

then to return the address all you need is:

```
    return owners[_id];
```

The only way you'd need to append .address is if you had a mapping which contained a struct which had an address member.

Comment: the code is actually  mapping(address => uint) tokens;  not unit==>address. does that make a difference?

Comment: Well, yes, because there's no easy way to derive the reverse mapping which seems to be what you are looking for.  But if you are using OpenZeps ERC721, you can just call ownerOf(tokenId) to get the address of the owner.  I'm not 100% sure what you are looking for when you ask for tokens[3].address.  Are you looking for address of owner?  Tokens don't have their own individual "address".  PS can't really read the code if you post it in a comment.  You shoudl edit your question and include the code properly formatted.

Comment: ok, will do. thank you for the advice, I am still getting the hang of this format.

Comment: Looks like you've deleted your original question.    You should include the original question so people understand what you are trying to figure out.  While you're at it, you might say more about exactly what you are asking.